mongodb aggregation help. Remove a group by field
I need to group by an $hour field so I can match for specific hours in my query, but the end results I do not want that _id.hour in the output.  I tried adding a 2nd group by, but the results are still showing multiple records of the same keywordid because it's returning results based on the first groupby which has multiple hours in the results.
db.getCollection("yahoohourlyquick").aggregate([{
"$match": {
     "pid" : {"$in" : [759]},
        "date":      {"$gte": new ISODate('2024-03-29')},
        "clicks":    {"$gt": 0},
        "graphdata": {"$regex": "^rs-"},
    },
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "date":   {"$hour" : "$date"},
            "pid":       "$pid",
            "keywordid": "$graphdata",
        },
        "rpc": {"$avg": "$cpc"},
        "clicks" : {"$sum" : "$clicks"},
    },
},
{
    "$match" : {
      "_id.date" : {$in:[1,2,3]}, 
      "clicks" : {"$gte" : 10}
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "pid":       "$pid",
            "keywordid": "$graphdata",
        },
        "data" : {$push: {
            "clicks" : "$clicks",
            "rpc" : "$rpc",
            "keywordid" : "$_id.keywordid",
            "pid" : "$_id.pid"
        }}
    },
},
{$unwind : "$data"},
{
    "$project": {
          _id : 0,
          "pid" : "$data.pid",
          "keywordid" : "$data.keywordid",
          "clicks" : "$data.clicks",
          "rpc" : "$data.rpc"
     },
},
{
   "$sort" : {"rpc":-1}
   }
])  

My goals is to just have the output contain
PID,KEYWORDID,SUM OF THE CLICKS, AVERAGE RPCS.   There should not be rows with the same keywordid but I can't seem to solve this problem.
Example results when I run this:

you can see keywordid "rs-2391021771" is in there twice because it has data for multiple hours.    I don't want each hour broken out in the results.

Would be great if you can provide sample data & expected output. Or you can create a Mongo Playground with your data & query. Thanks.

I finally got it working.
db.getCollection("yahoohourlyquick").aggregate([{
"$match": {
     "pid" : {"$in" : [759]},
        "date":      {"$gte": new ISODate('2024-03-29')},
        "clicks":    {"$gt": 0},
        "graphdata": {"$regex": "^rs-"},
    },
},
{
    "$project": {
          "hour":   {"$hour" : "$date"},
          "pid" : "$pid",
          "keywordid" : "$graphdata",
          "rpc" : "$cpc",
          "clicks" : "$clicks"
     },
},
{
    "$match" : {
      "hour" : {$in:[23,0,1]}, 
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "pid":       "$pid",
            "keywordid": "$keywordid",
        },
        "rpc": {"$avg": "$rpc"},
        "clicks" : {"$sum" : "$clicks"},
    },
},
{
    "$match" : {
      "clicks" : {"$gte" : 10}
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
          "pid" : "$_id.pid",
          "keywordid" : "$_id.keywordid",
          "rpc" : "$rpc",
          "clicks" : "$clicks"
     },
},
{
   "$sort" : {"rpc":-1}
   } 
])


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
